# Uninstalling Cairo Dock doesn't work

Tags: 15.10, cairo-dock

I installed Cairo Dock to try it, but I did not liked it. But uninstalling in the Software Center did not work, because the Cairo Dock is still sticking at the bottom of my screen. Here on askubuntu.com i found many answers and i tried nearly all of them, but i still see the Cairo Dock down there at my screen, and often the terminal said that "cairo-dock" is not installed or similar errors.

Please help me, because the this dock is a very annoying thing on my screen.

---

Solved.

Comment: Kill the process?

Comment: `killall cairo-dock` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem but this does it from terminal command line:

```
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

from : [Cairo-Dock - Uninstall | Glx-Dock](http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Uninstall&lang=en)

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can try that command , it's helpfull :

```
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If you want to keep the configuration files:

```
sudo dpkg -r cairo-dock-plug-ins_++version++
```

and

```
sudo dpkg -r cairo-dock_++version++
```

But if you want to completely remove the dock including the configuration files:

```
sudo dpkg -P cairo-dock-plug-ins_++version++
```

and

```
sudo dpkg -P cairo-dock_++version++
```

I wish that be usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

**NONE OF THE ABOVE ANSWERS WORKED FOR ME**
I'm using ubuntu 22.04. Out of curiosity, I installed Cairo-dock and now I can't remove it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**NONE OF THE ABOVE ANSWERS WORKED FOR ME**
I'm using ubuntu 22.04. Out of curiosity, I installed the Cairo dock and now I can't remove it anymore.

Okay, here is an official link to show you how to remove it. I removed it successfully :)

http://www.glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Uninstall&lang=en